# How to move CSS background based on cursor/finger position without using background-position property?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working on a small app where the user move the background with his mouse or his finger on the screen.

You can find a demo here: http://kaleidoscope-experiment.herokuapp.com/

The `background-position` is defined by the position of the cursor/finger using this kind of code:

```
// mobile
position = e.touches[0].pageX + 'px ' + e.touches[0].pageY + 'px';

// desktop
position = e.pageX + 'px ' + e.pageY + 'px';
```

However, I have significant lags on mobile and tablet and the background is "clipping".

Do you know if there is any alternative to `background-position` (`transform`?), to move the background based on the cursor/mouse position?

Comment: I think clipping might be inevitable - unless you have a specific range, it's not clear how you want it to be. do you have a working demo or something similar?

Comment: @Aziz I added a link to a demo in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll your own just use a combination of the jQuery mousemove function in combination with CSS3 transforms. Something along the lines of this:

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
    msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
    console.log( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
    $("#movingobject").css('transform', 'translate(' + event.pageY /4 + 'px,' + -event.pageX /4+ 'px)');
    });
```

Here is the reference fiddle that i got from stackoverflow
http://jsfiddle.net/ZmZhw/

There are number of js plugin that are available which will give u some smooth transition and performance also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, I'm looking for a infinite background to move not a specific element to translate.